# when i use mobile data, imageview is not updated but when using wifi it is updated

Tags: java, android, mysql, mobile

so im developing an android mobile apps which can upload data and image to database. it all works for the database part which im using mysql and hosting. the only problem that im having right now is when im using wifi, the imageView is immediately updated with the newest image that i have uploaded but when im using mobile data, the imageView wont refresh to the newest image that i uploaded. pls give any idea on how i could repair this error. tqvm in advanced[image: image uploaded with mobile data][image: preview image is not updated using mobile data][image: preview image is updated using wifi]

1.AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.cliniclocum">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/caduceus_medicine_symbol_white_black_button"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainPageLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration_page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ClinicOwnerMainPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clinic_owner_main_page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoctorMainPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_doctor_main_page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ClinicOwnerProfilePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clinic_owner_profile_page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ClinicOwnerUploadImagePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clinic_owner_upload_image" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ClinicOwnerSetLocumJobPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clinic_owner_set_locum_job" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CoViewLocumPosted"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_co_view_locum_posted" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CoUpdateLocumPostedDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_co_locum_posted_details" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoProfilePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_do_profile_page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoUploadApcImage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_do_upload_apc_image" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoViewLocumPost"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_do_view_locum_post" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoViewLocumDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_do_view_locum_details" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoViewClinicProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_do_view_clinic_profile" />
    <activity android:name=".CoImageFullScreen" />
</application>
```

2.ProfilePage.java

```
public class ClinicOwnerProfilePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView textViewUserRole;

EditText editTextCoProfilePageName, editTextCoProfilePageAddress, editTextCoProfilePageClinicOwnerName, editTextCoProfileFacilities;
Button buttonCoProfileUploadClinicImage, buttonCoProfileUpdateProfile;

Spinner spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

private ImageView imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage;
private Bitmap bitmap;
String imagePath;

private ProgressDialog loading;

String receiveSpEmail;
String passedSpPatientTurnover;

// added for refreshing event
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clinic_owner_profile_page);

    textViewUserRole = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCoUserRole);

    editTextCoProfilePageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCoProfileName);
    editTextCoProfilePageAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCoProfileAddress);
    editTextCoProfilePageClinicOwnerName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCoProfileClinicOwnerName);
    editTextCoProfileFacilities = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCoProfileFacilities);

    buttonCoProfileUploadClinicImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCoProfileUploadImage);
    buttonCoProfileUpdateProfile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCoProfileUpdateProfile);

    buttonCoProfileUploadClinicImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonCoProfileUpdateProfile.setOnClickListener(this);

    spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spCoProfileUpdatePatientTurnover);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SpinnerCoUpdatePatientTurnover, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            passedSpPatientTurnover = spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    receiveSpEmail();
    getCoProfileData();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCoProfileClinicImage);
    //getCoImageProfile();
    getImage();


    /*imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // to send bitmap using intent, we need to change it into ByteArray first and putting byteArray into the intent extra
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 25, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(ClinicOwnerProfilePage.this, CoImageFullScreen.class);
            fullScreenIntent.putExtra("CoImage", byteArray);
            startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
        }
    });*/

    //added for pull to refresh

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getImage();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }

    });

    //end of refreshing event

}

public void receiveSpEmail(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PassingEmail", MODE_PRIVATE);
    receiveSpEmail = preferences.getString("passEmail", "..");
    textViewUserRole.setText(receiveSpEmail);

}

private void getCoProfileData() {
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = ClinicOwnerGetProfile.DATA_URL+receiveSpEmail.toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ClinicOwnerProfilePage.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String clinic_name="";
    String address = "";
    String clinicownername = "";
    String facilities = "";
    String patient_turnover = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ClinicOwnerGetProfile.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject clinicOwnerData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        clinic_name = clinicOwnerData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetProfile.KEY_NAME);
        address = clinicOwnerData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetProfile.KEY_ADDRESS);
        clinicownername = clinicOwnerData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetProfile.KEY_CLINICOWNERNAME);
        facilities = clinicOwnerData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetProfile.KEY_FACILITIES);
        patient_turnover = clinicOwnerData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetProfile.KEY_PATIENT_TURNOVER);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    editTextCoProfilePageName.setText(clinic_name);
    editTextCoProfilePageAddress.setText(address);
    editTextCoProfilePageClinicOwnerName.setText(clinicownername);
    editTextCoProfileFacilities.setText(facilities);

    for (int i = 0; i < spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(patient_turnover)) {
            spinnerCoProfilePatientTurnover.setSelection(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/*//added for retrieve image - 13/2/16
private void getCoImageProfile() {

    String url = ClinicOwnerGetImage.DATA_URL+receiveSpEmail.toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showImageJSON(response);
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(imagePath);
            imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ClinicOwnerProfilePage.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

private void showImageJSON(String response){
    String image="";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ClinicOwnerGetImage.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject employeeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        image = employeeData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetImage.KEY_CLINIC_IMAGE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imagePath = image;

    // added for refreshing event - 5/3
    if(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    // end of refreshing

}
public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
//end of retrieve image*/

//new image getter method - 12/3
private void getImage() {

    String email = receiveSpEmail.toString();


    class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ClinicOwnerProfilePage.this,"Please wait...","Fetching Image...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {
            super.onPostExecute(b);
            loading.dismiss();
            imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage.setImageBitmap(b);
            // added for refreshing event - 5/3
            if(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
            {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
            // end of refreshing
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String receiveSpEmail = params[0];
            String add = "http://cliniclocum.org/CoGetImageProfile.php?email="+receiveSpEmail;
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
    }

    GetImage gi = new GetImage();
    gi.execute(email);
}

//end of new method

public void saveSpCoProfile(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PassingCoProfile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("passCoAddress", editTextCoProfilePageAddress.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("passCoClinicName", editTextCoProfilePageName.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnCoProfileUploadImage:
            Intent CoUploadImage = new Intent(this, ClinicOwnerUploadImagePage.class);
            startActivity(CoUploadImage);
            break;

        case R.id.btnCoProfileUpdateProfile:
            if(editTextCoProfilePageName.getText().toString().equals("")|| editTextCoProfilePageAddress.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Clinic Name and Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                String type = "CoUpdate";
                String update_CoName = editTextCoProfilePageName.getText().toString();
                String update_CoAddress = editTextCoProfilePageAddress.getText().toString();
                String update_CoClinicOwnerName = editTextCoProfilePageClinicOwnerName.getText().toString();
                String update_CoFacilities = editTextCoProfileFacilities.getText().toString();
                String update_CoPatientTurnover = passedSpPatientTurnover;


                CoUpdateBackgroundWorker coUpdateBackgroundWorker = new CoUpdateBackgroundWorker(this);
                coUpdateBackgroundWorker.execute(type, receiveSpEmail, update_CoName, update_CoAddress, update_CoClinicOwnerName, update_CoFacilities, update_CoPatientTurnover);

                coUpdateBackgroundWorker.setOnTaskFinishedListener(new CoUpdateBackgroundWorker.OnTaskFinishedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTaskFinished(String result) {

                        switch (result) {

                            case "Profile Updated":
                                saveSpCoProfile();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent successIntent = new Intent(ClinicOwnerProfilePage.this, ClinicOwnerMainPage.class);
                                startActivity(successIntent);
                                break;

                            default:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
            break;

    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(ClinicOwnerProfilePage.this, ClinicOwnerMainPage.class);
    startActivity(backIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Internet Permission In your **menifests** file Like this:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.XYZ.AppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.XYZ.AppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cricon"
    android:label="@string/activity_logoN"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: ive included <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in the manifest. it also include the mobile data right? or do i need a specific permission for mobile data?

Comment: what's your actual problem imageview takes time to update or it's not update...please clear it..n paste the code where you update the image..

Comment: when i use mobile data, the image is uploaded to the database but the imageView will not update to the newest image that i have uploaded. no matter how many times i refresh. and when i use wifi, it only takes pull to refresh once to update the imageView to the latest uploaded image.

Comment: please paste your menifests file code and getting data from database...please show me your code....

Comment: ive updated the question. tqvm for helping. really appreciate it. btw, this is my first app so im really new to android development. hope that i can solve this problem though.